# How do you counter Vladimir?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have no idea how to face Vladimir - every time I face him I lose.

I normally play as Ashe, Corki, Lulu, or Brand, if that makes a difference.

The trouble I have is that he turret dives so well thanks to his pool. Is there anything I can do to counter this?

Comment: Hello, Conjim, and welcome to gaming! What part about Vladimir are you finding particularly difficult? The more detail you can offer, the more detailed our answers can be!

Comment: What lanes are you playing? Are you high enough ELO so that you normally face him solo in mid/top or are you still playing duo lanes?

Comment: I normally face him solo mid and him turrent diving me and him not dieing because of his pool this champion is the only one that I have no idea how to counter

Comment: Excellent! I've added that back into the main body of your post, conjim.

Comment: wold hexdrinker help against Vladimir?

Comment: Yes, it is a good item if you are behind against strong magic users.

Comment: how do you get these questions into the the gg classic running for the rp?

Comment: Honestly you shouldn't have any problems dealing with vlad early as brand. Brand has an insane range on at least two of his abilities. Number one rule for fighting a vlad is to force his pool use at a time that is not beneficial to him. After he has pooled he is extremely vulnerable to all of your attacks. Just make sure you don't miss your q after he is on fire and has pooled already.

Answer (score 2):

To specifically counter Vladimir you should choose a champion with some or all of the following tools in their kit:

- A gap closer (If Melee)
- Burst Damage
- Crowd Control.

By selecting a champion with two or more of these tools you will be able to pressure Vladimir into using his pool which uses a considerable amount of his health. By pressuring him early and often you will deny him farm which delay his very strong late game presence.

Comment: Or pick Fiddlestick. He counters too hard, and is a teamfight son of a gun.

Answer (score 1):

I main as an AP player in around 2k ELO, so I've had my share of Vladimirs past 2 years!

Laning vs. him:
Vladimir is actually rather weak early game due to the fact that his Q (Transfusion) is on a high cooldown and doesn't heal for much. If you're playing offensive AP champs who are strong early (Cassiopeia, Ryze, Ziggs, Kennen) you can punish him by going aggressive. Also make sure you exploit his short range on his Q.

Playing vs. him during teamfights/in general:
Since he is a short-ranged caster, you can avoid most of his damage with good positioning; make sure you stay behind your tanks.
Also, if he's really fed you can go for Quicksilver Sash to cleanse his ultimate off, which shuts down a lot of his damage.
Heal's debuff helps a lot too, since he has quite a lot of sustain, so make sure to grab that, or at least try to make sure the AP on your team has it.

Hopefully that helped, good luck!

Comment: Every vlad I face is very very aggressive and even jump into current range to kill me

Comment: in your opinion would hexdrinker be a good counter to his power

Comment: Hexdrinker might be a good choice if you're playing a bruiser top against vlad or a double ap setup(kennen vlad for instance). Especially since they've added an upgrade for it, probably worth upgrading once you get Frozen mallet + atmas.

Comment: Fight Fire with more fire. Well, it doesn't really deserve a full answer, but I know FiddleStick counters Vlad very very hard. Mainly because his drain will keep dealing damage when vlad stays in pool. Thus, go in contact with him, fear and start using your drain. He will have absolutely no way (beside flash) to escape your drain. Try it, it's almost the only matchup Fiddle is pretty good in.

Answer (score 1):

I main Vlad so I tend to see what counters work the best. The best kind of counters are reduced healing put on him. Fizz's passive or greivous wounds are especially strong when it comes to laning sustain against him. His early game is truly his biggest weakness and he is not very apt at dealing with cc or champs with high mobility. I recommend you just don't let him lane harass, out aggress early and play it smart. Engage after he q's because he doesn't have anything to mitigate a counter attack for 4-5 seconds even when he is higher levels.

Vlad has a lot of exploitable weaknesses, and as always, a good jungler counters everything he does.

Answer (score 0):

To counter Vladimir and his sustained laning phase, you will have to have Ignite with you, which is mandatory. After this you have to choose carefully who you pick against him... He is countered by some champs, such as Malzahar, Kog'Maw and Gangplank.

If you are stuck with any other champion against him, all you can do in the laning phase is carefully freeze your lane at your tower and hope for the best... I hope you will find this helpful in the future.

Comment: I normally go with ignite and exhaust or ignite and heal

Comment: heal or flash with ignite are both good against him would not recommend exhaust as it is not very useful against him due to his pool but in the long run exhaust is good for shutting carries down so all of those above u said are good and viable...

Answer (score 0):

To counter Vladimir you need a champion with burst damage and CC. Brand should be a good choice against him cause of his burst. However, if your problem is his tower diving and his pool, I would suggest a hero with crowd control to stop him. See the link below for more info.

I got all this info from http://www.lolpro.com/guides/vladimir/71-vladimir-guide-top-lane/tips-tricks-synergies-and-counters It's a good site if you want to know builds or counters.

Comment: Can you please add the information in your link to your answer here? We try to discourage answers whose main body is comprised only of a link elsewhere due to the possibility of link rot.

Answer (score 0):

[Grievous Wounds](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Grievous_Wounds) is a plus if you can make use of it (e.g. [Morellonomicon](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Morellonomicon)). Since his `Q` (`Transfusion`) has a fairly long CD in the early levels, when Vlad uses it you should try to harass him during this time so he doesn't use it on you. Remember that he has no mana and his character revolves around sustain so you need to either counter his sustain or burst him down. Successful early harassment can easily zone Vlad out and prevent him from sustaining in lane. Don't try to just simply trade blows with him.

A standard 1v1 combo using Vlad is to `R` (`Hemoplague`), `Ignite`, `Q`, `E` (`Tides of Blood`), `W` (`Sanguine Pool`) if needed, and followed by `Q` and `E`. Vlad's R boosts all incoming damages so that's the first thing to avoid. While using W, certain abilities do still affect him such as existing DoT or certain CC (e.g. Veigar's Event Horizon). His `E` is easily avoided and pay attention to how many stacks (max of 4) Vlad has as it boosts his damage and sustain; late game it's usually fairly trivial to keep it at max stacks as Vlad can easily recover the HP used to cast the ability. Try to bait out his `W` so you can effectively dive him as the CD is fairly long.